# How many $N$ in $[100,400]$ such that $N^N$ is perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

How many $N$ in $[100,400]$ such that $N^N$ is perfect square? A perfect square is a number that can be represented as $N=a^2$ for some $a$.

How would you approach this? I'm  struggling to see a clear path to answering this?

Comment: $N$ is either an odd square or is even

Comment: @KentaS how do you know that?

Comment: If $N$ is even, $N^N=(N^{N/2})^2$. Otherwise, $N$ is odd. Then $N^N=(N^{(N-1)/2})^2N$, so $N^N$ is a perfect square iff $N$ is a perfect square

Comment: @KentaS I cant see the logic behind the first sentence

Comment: You can't see the logic behind the first sentence?  That if $N$ is even then $N^N = (N^{N/2})^2$?  Do you see it at least that for specific example that $4^4 = 16^2$ since they both equal $256$?

Comment: i cant see the last sentence now @KentaS

Comment: @JMoravitz i understand that sentence now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between $100$ to $400$ there are $151$ even numbers (including $100$). These numbers are perfectly divisible by $2$. Therefore $N^N$ can be written as $N^{\frac{N}2\cdot 2}$. Square root of this $N^{N/2}$. Therefore if $N$ is even $N^N$ is a perfect square.

Now lets take the case of remaining $149$ odd numbers $(101, 103, \ldots, 399)$. $\sqrt{N^N} = N^{N/2} = (N^{0.5N})$. If $N$ is a odd number and perfect square, then $N^N$ is perfect square. Between $101$ and $399$ we have $5$ odd perfect squares ($11^2 = 121, 13^2 = 169, 15^2 = 225, 17^2 = 289, 19^2 = 361$).

Therefore in total we have $156$ numbers ($151$ even + $5$ odd) between $[100 400]$ such $N^N$ is perfect square